# Angular 7.3.9 - Could not find JSESSIONID in application cookies

Tags: angular, tomcat, cookies, angular-httpclient

I have a front-end written in Angular 7.3.9 which runs on `localhost:4200` and back-end running on Tomcat on `localhost:8086`. I've made a login request, but Set-Cookie was not sent in the response header.

The request header:

```
! Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/welcome
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

The response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 09:34:28 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I could not see the HttpOnly JSESSIONID in application/cookies as well, it must be like this: `JSESSIONID=0D3A40EBDF83F0202DAA2315DD6951FC; Path=/; HttpOnly`

I've tried to build the application and run it with tomcat server and get desired response.

The request header:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:8086
Origin: http://localhost:8086
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8086/welcome
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

The response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 08:56:47 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0D3A40EBDF83F0202DAA2315DD6951FC; Path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

this is my request code:

```js
this.authService.login(user)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    error => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
```

auth.service.ts

```js
login(data) {
    data["flag"] = 'new_login';
    let url = 'http://localhost:8086/api/user';
    let body = this.helper.toBodyString(data);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      })
    }
    return this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(user => {
          if (user && user.msg === '') {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
          }
          console.log(user);

          return user;
        }),
        catchError(this.helper.handleError)
      );
  }
```

[JSESSIONID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl8xE.png)

Comment: I really don;t understand what you are asking and what's the problem. You say that you didn;t get the cookie, yet at the same time you say that you received it. So what;s the actual problem ?

Comment: Sorry about that, the things is I only receive it when I run it on the same port 8086, when I request from localhost:4200 to localhost:8086 I could not get that cookie.